# mysql order position DESC but put first if position="chef"

Tags: mysql, sorting

the problem: mysql order position DESC but put first if position="chef"
I want to order descending but put some things first. How is the syntax for that?

Comment: could you explain your problem in detail

Comment: what have you done so far? can you post some columns in your table?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
ORDER BY
   CASE 
     WHEN position="chef" THEN 0
     ELSE 1 
   END,
   position DESC
```

Adding more WHEN conditions allows you to prioritise some positions

```
ORDER BY
   CASE 
     WHEN position="chef" THEN 0  -- first
     WHEN position="dogsbody" THEN 99 -- last
     ELSE 1 
   END,
   position DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY column1='Put This First' DESC, column1;
```

This will put the rows that have `column1='Put This First'` first, then will proceed to order everything else based on column1.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY column1=1 DESC, column2;
```

This is another example. Will put rows where `column1=1` first, then will order the rest of the rows based on the value of column2.